# Problems with a job that rebuilds indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, maintenance-plans, index-maintenance

We have a Maintenance Plan (MP) job that rebuilds indexes every week.

The last time, the job failed because of a deadlock. Should I rerun the whole job, or do I just need to rerun the rebuild of the deadlocked index?

The rebuilding of indexes is being performed using standard tools of MP plan.

As I understand it, if a standard MP job for index rebuild stopped because of deadlock, it means that other indexes (after the deadlocked index) also need to rebuild? Or MP job will rebuild all indexes except this one that failed?

Here is example of entry from job history:

> Progress: 2017-09-30 21:00:33.06
>   Source: Rebuild Index Task
>   Executing query "USE []  ".: 0% complete
>   End Progress
>   Progress: 2017-09...
>   The package execution fa...
>   The step failed.

There is no information about which index rebuilds completed, only information that a query started to execute. Looks like one way to check what was rebuilt or not is to check index fragmentation for whole database using T-SQL scripts?

There is only information about deadlock and nothing more in MP log.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should rebuild index which it deadlocked on, and rebuild any other indexes which not did not occur afterwards- if whole job failed and stopped.
2. Hopefully you are rebuilding indexes, during less busy times, say nighttime or after hours. If you have no choice, and have a continuously busy system,
   Please Rebuild with [Online option](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2361/rebuilding-sql-server-indexes-using-the-online-option/),

   ```
   ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[Test] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON);
   ```
3. Additionally, I would only rebuild indexes which require it.  [Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) website has an option to reorganize indexes say with 5% Fragmentation, and rebuild for 30% Fragmentation. I don't think Windows SQL Server Maintenance has this option yet.

   ```
   EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
   @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
   @FragmentationLow = NULL,
   @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
   @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
   @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
   @FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
   @UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
   @OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
   ```

Check when the deadlock occurred, and how the long the total job duration lasted. If those points meet, then the job stopped at the deadlock. If the job duration lasted longer than deadlock, more indexes were rebuilt.